# Add a question and answer filter to /users page

Tags: feature-request, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a "number of active users" statistic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103247/add-a-number-of-active-users-statistic)

We're having a discussion on the scope of our site and were wondering what users are actually asking and answering questions.

I would like new filters on the /users page for **questions** and **answers** to get an idea who our real users are.

Especially given that Beta sites aren't included in the Data Explorer, this would give us an idea if its new or regular users asking questions. The reputation filter throws everything on a big heap and makes it harder to draw any conclusions.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are asking for this:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110370/users-ordered-by-questions-asked

And

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110373/users-ordered-by-answers-provided

---

I do not think we should add this to the main site. The list of prolific askers has been criticized in the past, people complain that they do not give back enough. Thus adding it as a sort order would be a "shame list" .... the users pages is trying to promote awesome, not shame people.

The prolific answerer list is more interesting, however, I feel that it is just too close to `order by Reputation desc` to be needed.

Comment: All nice and dandy if Data.se supported beta sites, which it doesnt. But I get we dont to shame people. Sad though that a small group of users turn asking a lot questions into something negative :-\

Comment: I did not decline this for that reason exactly, I am not against extending tools or mod pages to display this ... but am reluctant to add it to the main UI

Comment: Well that would be a nice midground obviously. Though Im not sure what the best stats would be. I asked it this way because it fit an existing feature not because it was the best way to see who your most avid users are.

Comment: sure, I am fine for you to reboot this, we want to make it as easy as possible for early phases of a site.

Comment: I closed it as a dupe of Fabian's question, because he's simply asking for a similar statistic.